# how to implement a bookcase like ibook?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i wanna implement a bookcase like as ibook's bookcase.who can tell me how to do it? has any source ? thanks.

i cant find some useful case to learn how to do it.

Comment: No such thing as “ibook”. I think you are trying to refer to “iBooks”. Please capitalize properly also; it makes it easier for those of us who would try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a background picture to the UITableView, and make a custom cell, which do the drawing stuff (the book artworks, the background image).